# Basic categories cheat sheet

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Has anyone come across a cheat sheet containing basic properties of the most well-known categories (i.e. does it have (co)products, (co)equalizers, (co)limits, etc?)?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with your 'question' is that it isn't an actual question, but that's easily fixable and obviously not worthy of a downvote. $+1$.

Comment: Yeah. It might be good to explicitly make this a question.

Comment: Yeah. Me want, too.

Comment: @GitGud: Ok, fixed that.

Comment: I think making such a list yourself is a good exercise. Most well-known categories are complete and cocomplete and it's a good exercise to figure out how to construct the corresponding limits and colimits.

Answer (score 5):

This book is not exactly a cheat sheet, but it's along the lines of what you're asking for.

Examples in Category Theory by Grigore Calugareanu and Ioan Purdea.
http://math.ubbcluj.ro/~calu/BOO-0-14.pdf
(Book in progress)

Answer (score 5):

There has been sporadic interest at the nLab in creating a database of categories and their properties. Right now such a project is dormant (and I think in principle we'd be interested if someone wants to take this up -- inquiries may be posted to the [nForum](http://nforum.mathforge.org/)), but for the moment see what we have [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/database+of+categories).

There is some accompanying discussion at the nForum, started by someone who wanted to make this a senior undergraduate project, [here](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/1754/).